# Can I apply Kaiser Rule without knowing the eigenvalues?

Tags: self-study, pca, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis, eigenvalues

Kaiser's rule suggests the number of principal components to be included in an analysis by looking at eigenvalues. If I'm given standard deviations only, instead of eigenvalues, can I still somehow use the Kaiser rule?
*This question was asked in a multivariate exam.*

Comment: the eigenvalues are the squared standard deviations.

Comment: standard deviations _of what_?

Comment: @ttnphns the standard deviations of the principal components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, the variances of the principal components (PCs) are given by the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix. Therefore, the PCs' standard deviations are just the eigenvalues' square root. So you can safely apply the Kaiser rule to the standard deviations.